# How can get data complicated json response in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have a booking listing page. I tried to get data from json file. In **first format** result is getting but **second format** data is not getting. I have explained two format below. Please help me to solve this problem. I have added my code in plunker.

[Plunker Link](https://embed.plnkr.co/uPta1A9ED4UtESsaLAoB/)

**First**

```
    [
       {"_id": "57ee4e32f8f888dc11000029", "cabinname": "Foo", "user": "5818355ad2ae67e505431d5b"
       },
       {"_id": "57f22cf3f8f888800c000030", "cabinname": "Joo", "user": "5818355ad2ae67e505431d5b"
       },
       { "_id": "57f22cf3f8f888800c000031", "cabinname": "Maria", "user": "5818355ad2ae67e505431d5b"
       },
      {
       "_id": "57f22cf3f8f888800c000032", "cabinname": "Peter", "user": "5818355ad2ae67e505431d5b"
      },
      {"_id": "57f22cf3f8f888800c000033", "cabinname": "Declan", "user": "5818355ad2ae67e505431d5b"
       }
   ]
```

**Second**

```
{
  "bookingDetails": {
    "data": [
      {"_id": "57ee4e32f8f888dc11000029", "cabinname": "Foo", "user": "5818355ad2ae67e505431d5b"
      },
      {"_id": "57f22cf3f8f888800c000030", "cabinname": "Joo", "user": "5818355ad2ae67e505431d5b"
      },
      {
        "_id": "57f22cf3f8f888800c000031", "cabinname": "Maria", "user": "5818355ad2ae67e505431d5b"
      },
      {
        "_id": "57f22cf3f8f888800c000032", "cabinname": "Peter", "user": "5818355ad2ae67e505431d5b"
      },
      {
        "_id": "57f22cf3f8f888800c000033", "cabinname": "Declan", "user": "5818355ad2ae67e505431d5b"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Json file is oncluded in **apidata -> testData.json**

**app -> booking -> booking.service.ts**

```
getBooking(): Promise<Bookings[]> {
        return this.http.get(this._url)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json() as Bookings[])
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

**app -> booking -> booking.component.ts**

```
export class BookingComponent implements OnInit {
    bookings: Bookings[];
    constructor(private employeeService: BookingService) {}
    getBooking(): void {
        /*this.employeeService.getEmployee().then(employees => this.employees = employees);*/
        this.employeeService.getBooking().then(bookings => this.bookings = bookings);
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getBooking();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into using `subscribe` instead of `promise`.
But, if you want to use promises, change your **booking.service.ts** file to

```
getBooking(): Promise<Bookings[]> {
        return this.http.get(this._url)
            .map(response => response.json().bookingDetails.data as Bookings[])
            .toPromise()
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your plunker has errors, but you need to correct your service implementation and the way you consume it in `angular2`.

Change the *booking.service.ts* code, like:

```
getBooking(): Promise<Bookings[]> {
        return this.http.get(this._url)
            .map(response => response.json().bookingDetails.data as Bookings[])
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

and code in *booking.component.ts* , like:

```
this.employeeService.getBooking().subscribe(bookings => this.bookings = bookings );
```